# Register functions or strings into Symfony dependency injection container

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I would like to use Symfony di container to register anonymous functions or strings. Ideally using PSR11 API, something like this:

```
$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
$containerBuilder->register('databasehost', '127.0.0.1');
$containerBuilder->register('Database', function($c) {
   return new Database($c->get('databasehost'));
};
$containerBuilder->get('Database')->insertInto(...);
```

Is it possible? How?

Comment: As far as strings go, you would use the [parameter functionality](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html).  There is no direct support for closures as far as I know.  You could probably use the [factory capablity](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html).  The Symfony container defines services differently then many of the other containers you might see out there.  It might be best to work through the docs and follow the examples.

Answer (score 0):

`databasehost` is a parameter, while you're trying to register it as a service.
Instead, you should set it via `setParameter` method to make it indeed a parameter.

Then you can use it to inject into service with `addArgument` method.

There's a very similar example in [DIC Component docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html):

```
$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
$containerBuilder->setParameter('mailer.transport', 'sendmail');
$containerBuilder
    ->register('mailer', 'Mailer')
    ->addArgument('%mailer.transport%');
```

So your code should be something like:

```
$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
$containerBuilder->setParameter('databasehost', '127.0.0.1');
$containerBuilder
    ->register('Database', 'Database')
    ->addArgument('%databasehost%');
```

And by the way, PSR-11 does not say anything about building the cointainer, but only about retrieving services from it. It defines only `get` and `has` methods.

P.S. I assumed that `Datatabase` what just a typo and you meant `Database`